Why do realestate webapp shows only static interactive instead of making everything dynamic?
I am developing a webapp where users can click on layout of the real-estate, and on clicking it it shows the towers and individual floors with svg and images. I am saying should i make it static or dynamic which shows availibilty and everything, im facing issues when the layout has villas or standalone buildings. Is it recommended to make it fully dynamic or static ?
i tried making a fixed layout to store the data like
apartment contains array of objects of towers , floors , flats
like towers:[{towerid, svgurl, imageurl},...]
floors:[{floorid, svgurl, imageurl},...]... etc
